# Excel to SQL via VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

Hoping someone can assist with the following :

I have a excel file with only one column I need to insert to a table in sql.

The column contains roughly 100 000 rows + and with the current code (i got this on the net as well and changed it a bit to work for me) its just taking a bit too long (15 mins...)

I know it would be much easier to do it via SSIS or SSMS import wizard, but for this exercise i need to do it via vba.

**This is the code im using currently :**

```vb
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim strn_reference As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=DNA-*******;Initial Catalog=*****;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    conn.Execute "truncate table dbo.MyTable"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        strn_reference = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)


        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
        conn.Execute "insert into dbo.MyTable (trn_reference) values ('" & strn_reference & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Reference Numbers imported."

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End With
End Sub
```

Now this works but, its slow so i need it to maybe insert in batches? But since i'm extremely new to VBA , I have no idea how to do this?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
I'm very rusty with VBA, but I remember a couple of things.
VBA is based on OLE automation, every call to the object model of Excel requires marshalling, so it should be minimized. 
For the batch insert, the best would be a BulkInsert, but just to stay with your example, this is my code. It took less than 1 sec for 30.000 rows, but maybe my PC is better than yours.
I added a replace ' with '' to minimize problems with SQL Injection

```
Public Sub SaveData()

     Dim r As Range
     Dim c As Range

     Set r = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

     Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
     conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=StackOverflow;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

     Dim iRowNo As Integer
     Dim strn_reference As String
     Dim batchInsert As String

     Dim batchSize As Integer
     batchSize = 1000

     conn.Execute "truncate table dbo.MyTable"

     iRowNo = 0
     For Each cl In r
         iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
         batchInsert = batchInsert + (IIf(iRowNo > 1, ",", "")) + "('" & Replace(cl.Value2, "'", "''") & "')"
         If (iRowNo = batchSize) Then
             conn.Execute "insert into dbo.MyTable (trn_reference) Values " & batchInsert
             iRowNo = 0
             batchInsert = ""
         End If
     Next
     If Len(batchInsert) > 0 Then conn.Execute "insert into dbo.MyTable (trn_reference) Values " & batchInsert


    MsgBox "Reference Numbers imported."

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```